# Couldn't match expected type in Haskell error

Tags: haskell

I am having a problem with my code in Haskell. For the task we have data that has type Int for date and type Float for temperature degree. I have to define a function that returns the date on which the temperature has been close to the monthly average. Here is my code:

```
data Measuring = Temp Int Float

temp :: Measuring -> Float
temp (Temp _ tem) = tem

date :: Measuring -> Int
date (Temp dat _) = dat

averageTemp :: [Measuring] -> Float
averageTemp lst = (foldr1 (+) (map temp lst)) / fromIntegral (length lst)

closestToAverage :: [Measuring] -> Int
closestToAverage lst = foldl1 (\ t1 t2 -> if abs(averageTemp lst - t1) <= 
abs(averageTemp lst - t2)
then date t1 else date t2) lst
```

The error

```
"* Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `Float'
    * In the expression:
        foldl1
          (\ t1 t2
             -> if abs (averageTemp lst - t1) <= abs (averageTemp lst - t2) then
                    date t1
                else
                    date t2)
          lst
      In an equation for `closestToAverage':
          closestToAverage lst
            = foldl1
                (\ t1 t2
                   -> if abs (averageTemp lst - t1) <= abs (averageTemp lst - t2) then
                          date t1
                      else
                          date t2)
                lst
   |
83 | closestToAverage lst = foldl1 (\ t1 t2 -> if abs(averageTemp lst - t1) <= abs(averageTemp lst - t2)

   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"
```

Comment: What do you believe are the types of `t1` and `t2`?

Comment: Also, for your future reference: when reporting an error, it is best to report the *complete* error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of `foldl1` is `Foldable t => (a -> a -> a) -> t a -> a`. Notice that the higher order function must have the same output type as its two input types. Therefore, you need to return `t1` or `t2`, not `date t1` or `date t2`.

Also, since `t1` and `t2` have type `Measuring`, they can't be subtracted from `averageTemp lst`. You need to extract the `Float` value with `temp`.

```
closestToAverage :: [Measuring] -> Int
closestToAverage lst = date $ foldl1 (\t1 t2 ->
        if abs (averageTemp lst - temp t1) <= abs (averageTemp lst - temp t2)
            then t1
            else t2
    ) lst
```